# Importing CSV file into list in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file into the list in the marketing cloud(exactTarget). My CSV file contains First Name, Last Name and Email Address columns. Whenever I try to upload I get the following error and unable to upload the file.

[image]

My CSV file looks like this -
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend raising a support case and have them look at the error. Support may have more detail around the specific error that was raised.

Comment: Have to ask it because I've done it: Did you exit out of Excel before you tried to upload it?

Comment: Is Subscriber Key enabled in your account?  This would be a required field in your import if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised a case with the support team.

**The issue was that my FTP was not configured.** Even though I was uploading a file from the local machine, the FTP needs to be configured because if there is an error while uploading, the error result file will be placed on the FTP. The support team configured my FTP.